# Reading the old data by R from the some kind of cache

Tags: r

I am trying to import some data from the csv files ( which are autosaved from excel files ). Basically what I am trying to do is real time testing of an algo. So the tick data from excel are saved in a csv file and this csv file is picked up by R.

I am using

```
repeat{ 

SpotData = tryCatch(as.data.frame(read.csv(paste(xinputpath,"AUDJPYTickData.csv",sep=""),header=TRUE,sep=";")), error = function (e) e, warning = function(w) w)

....calculations...

 }
```

For most of the time it reads perfectly at high speed but sometimes, it just doesnt read the new file. No error but it just reads as if the old csv file still exists ( though the old one has been overwritten with new data ). So the SpotData is the same old data even though AUDJPYTickData.csv has a new timestamp with new data..

Has anyone faced this issue ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: This will be very difficult to troubleshoot without some kind of reproducibility. Can you try writing a script that automatically changes a csv file every couple of seconds?

Comment: Why don't you use `read.table` with `sep=","`?

Comment: I'd suggest putting in a `system.time` or similar call so you know exactly when you're `R` code tried to read the CSV file.  It sure looks at first glance like a race condition.

Comment: Thansk for your comments. Itamar, I read in some places that it's better to use read.csv than read.table. Let me try read.table and see if it solves the problem.. Carl. I have writing to csv files at important steps, to see where the problem is coming from...That's how I could find out that's it reading the same data again and again, though it continues the repeat loop...No error as well...Nograpes, what do you mean by automatically changing the csv file every couple of secs? Can you pls elaborate...I need to read the same file again and again to get the new updated data..

Comment: You haven't shown us what the "break" condition is for your `repeat` loop, so we can't tell how or why it repeats.  But please read my note: if you don't know when the source `csv` file is accessed vs. when it's been externally updated/modified, how do you expect to trace the problem?